# Pass variable from one function to another function

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a select like this:

```
<select class="form-control" ng-hide="Catalogos.length==0" ng-change="filtro(selected)" ng-model="selected" ng-options="item.Nombre for item in Catalogos "></select>
```

From there I get `selected value` in function like this:

```
$scope.filtro = function(selected) {
            $scope.selectedID = selected.ID;
        }
```

There I get `Id` for `selected value`, but now I want to send this `parameter` to another function like:

```
$scope.insertar = function(selected) {
                $scope.selectedID = selected.ID;
                if ($scope.catalogoid != null) {...
```

But `selected` always come undefined

Note: `$scope.insertar` triggers when I clic submit button

```
<button type="submit" class="btn blue" ng-click="insertar();">Aceptar</button>
```

Help is very appreciated! Regards

Comment: If the `<select>` and `<button>` are in the same scope, you can just use `ng-click="insertar(selected)"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just use the scope variable in your `insertar` function, not reassign it. Like this:

```
$scope.insertar = function() {
    var selectedId = $scope.selectedID; 
    if ($scope.catalogoid != null) {...
```